# Remove sticked Webcam Cover from MacBook Pro display

Tags: macbook-pro, display, webcam, macos

I few months ago I thoughtlessly placed a **sticky Webcam Cover** on my **MacBook Pro 2015** display. More in detail here is the [C-SLIDE product page](https://www.webcamcover.com/1-0-webcam-cover).

[image: sticky Webcam Cover placed on my MBP display]

I decided it's time to get rid of it but I'm not sure how to do so properly **without damaging the display's protection layer**.

Does anybody have experience with this kind of delicate operations? Is there any solvent expressly produced for that? Or would it help handling the laptop to a specialised shop or an Apple Store?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The damage is already done by whatever adhesive was applied. [Apple only recommends one solvent, pure water](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204172#portables), so I would use a [plastic spudger](https://www.amazon.com/plastic-spudger/s?k=plastic%20spudger) to gently dislodge the slide and then clean as best you can with water.

If you need a solvent, flip the screen upside down so any solvent drips over the normal top, now bottom onto the aluminum as opposed to dripping down the glass.

Chances are, the anti reflective coating will only be weakened or damaged in that top area or not at all. Damage to that layer there doesn’t spread, it’s only where a [solvent or physical abrasion](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/217485/5472) is present, so carefully control abrasion and solvents and your screen area should be safe.

Taking it to a shop that has tools and experience with solvents might be well worth the trip. Take them a pie or cookies, they will love the challenge and you’ll be in good hands if you’re not sure of your skills.

My hunch - you’ll get it off and whatever damage happened will be negligible and no issue. Please post a follow up picture once you’re done or answer how you solved this!

Answer (score 2):

I firstly asked a specialised shop to remove the cover for me, but - after a quick attempt with a solvent - they answered they couldn't take the risk of damaging the screen.

Therefore I eventually took a big breath and removed it by myself by delicately using my nail to leverage the cover.

Result: I was able to remove it from both laptops without leaving any trace on the screen. The only visible damage consists of a few light scratches left by the sliding lid.

Comment: I had the very same experiment. I just started using my nail and finally managed to take it off, without leaving any trace (except the fact that slider already made coating worn off)